# Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of '<button>'

Tags: javascript, angular

I just started learning Angular but I'm having the following error:
Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of `<button>`.
Searching on internet I just found similar errors but they are related to the fact the that the FormsModule is not imported, that doesn't seem to be my case.

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  Button = false;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!!
  </h1>
  <button [Disabled]="!Button">Click me</button>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: use lowercase for `Disabled` as in `<button [disabled]="!Button">Click me</button>`

Comment: You can't capitalize 'Disabled'. It must be 'disabled'.

Comment: Thanks @Maximus! That was the issue, I can't believe I was trying to find the problem and it was so simple :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
 <button [disabled]="!Button">Click me</button>
```